# Use different names for glossary entry in glossary and in text

Tags: glossaries

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{date}
{
name=1 October 1999,
description={He saw him}
}

\begin{document}

He saw him on \gls{date}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This will result in `1 October 1999` on the left of the glossary. However, I would like it to appear as `1999, 1 October` because it is easier to read dates in the glossary when the year always comes first. How can you use different names for a glossary entry depending on whether the glossary entries appears in the glossary or in the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New Answer

The `glossaries` package offers the keys `name` which is used in the glossary and `text` which is used in text (defaulting to `name` if `text` is not specified), so the correct way would be to use:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{date}
{
name={1999, 1 October},
description={He saw him},
text=1 October 1999
}

\begin{document}

He saw him on \gls{date}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The output doesn't change (so see below).

---

## Old Answer

One option could be to use a macro to store the `name` and change its definition for `\printglossaries`, I don't know how good this works out if you have more than one entry especially regarding the sorting (but there is the `sort` key to handle that):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*\myglossaryentry{1 October 1999}
\newglossaryentry{date}
{
name=\myglossaryentry,
description={He saw him},
sort={1999, 1 October}
}

\begin{document}

He saw him on \gls{date}.

\def\myglossaryentry{1999, 1 October}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]